# Ruby: replace the values in a key-value pair of an array of hashes with the values from a 2nd array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

In Ruby, I have an array of hashes and an array.  In my array of hashes, I want to replace the values in one of the key-value pairs with the values from my second array.  What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Example (I want to replace the value of "total" with the values from my second array):

**Array of hashes:**

```
 [{"date":"2012-05-27","total":1},{"date":"2012-05-28","total":9}]
```

**Array:**

```
 [1, 10]
```

**Desired Array of hashes:**

```
 [{"date":"2012-05-27","total":1},{"date":"2012-05-28","total":10}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.each_with_index {|e,i| hash_array[i]["total"] = e}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me.  When I run `array = [1, 10]` and `hash_array = [{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 1},{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 9}]` and `array.each_with_index {|e,i| hash_array[i]["total"] = e}` the result is `[1, 10]` while what I am looking for is `[{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 1},{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 10}]`

Comment: replace "total" with :total, because symbol is not a string. In your question there is string "total".

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I still get the same result:  `array = [1, 10]` and `hash_array = [{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 1},{:date => "2012-05-27", :total => 9}]` and `array.each_with_index {|e,i| hash_array[i][:total] = e}` the result is `[1, 10]`

Answer (score 1):

```
hashes = [{date: "2012-05-27", total: 1},{date: "2012-05-28", total: 9}] #unquoted keys
values = [1,10]

hashes.zip(values){|h,v| h[:total] = v}
p hashes #=>[{:date=>"2012-05-27", :total=>1}, {:date=>"2012-05-28", :total=>10}]
```